Consulta por velocidad de respuesta en mi sitio web - Operación de Registro de usuario
Como están? Hace poco tiempo lance mi aplicación web, y al momento de que un usuario se registre, noto que las velocidades de carga son bastante lentas, desde que el usuario hace click en "Registrar" hasta que se termina de ejecutar la operación de registro, pueden pasar unos 30 segundos.
Es en la única parte que sucede, por lo que considero que el problema esta en mi operación.
Estoy programando en C#, asp.net, respaldando en una base de datos de SQL, tengo programación en capas, donde tengo mi Persistencia, mi Logica y mis Entidades Compartidas.
Lo que deseo que suceda es que, 1ro se de el "Alta del Usuario" en mi Base de datos, que luego se le envíe al usuario un correo con sus datos de registro y se me envíe a mi correo una notificación de que alguien se registró en el sitio.
protected void LinkButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string membresia = "";
        if (rbMembresia.SelectedIndex == 0)
            membresia = "Gratis";
        else if (rbMembresia.SelectedIndex == 1)
            membresia = "Basico";
        else if (rbMembresia.SelectedIndex == 2)
            membresia = "Pro";
        else if (rbMembresia.SelectedIndex == 3)
            membresia = "Full";

        string correo = txtCorreo.Text.Trim();
        DateTime fecha = DateTime.Today;
        string usu = txtUsu.Text.Trim();
        string pass = txtPass.Text.Trim();

        Profesional unProfesional = new Profesional(0, usu, pass, correo, membresia);
        FabricaLogica.getLogicaProfesional().AltaProfesional(unProfesional);
        Session["Profesional"] = unProfesional;

        Limpiar();


        // Configuración del cliente SMTP según las recomendaciones del hosting
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("mail.XX.com")
        {
            Port = XX,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("info@XX.com", "XX"),
            EnableSsl = false
        };

        // Correo al administrador
        MailMessage correoParaAdmin = new MailMessage
        {
            From = new MailAddress("info@XX.com", "XX"),
            Subject = "Nuevo Registro de usuario",
            Body = "Se registró un nuevo usuario: <br />" +
                    "Usuario: " + usu + "<br />" +
                    "Correo: " + correo + "<br />" +
                    "Id de Usuario: " + unProfesional.Id_Profesional,
            IsBodyHtml = true
        };
        correoParaAdmin.To.Add("info@XX.com");

        // Correo al usuario
        MailMessage correoParaUsuario = new MailMessage
        {
            From = new MailAddress("info@XX.com", "XX"),
            Subject = "Registro Exitoso - Bienvenido a XX",
            Body = "Estimado/a " + usu.Trim() + ",<br />" +
                   "Le damos la bienvenida a XX!<br />" +
                   "Muchas gracias por elegir nuestro Software. Aquí están sus datos de Registro:<br />" +
                   "<br />Usuario: " + usu.Trim() + "<br />" +
                   "Contraseña: " + pass.Trim() + "<br />" +
                   "<br />Cualquier duda o sugerencia puede escribirnos a info@XX.com.<br />" +
                   "Atentamente, <br />El Equipo de XX.",
            IsBodyHtml = true
        };
        correoParaUsuario.To.Add(correo.Trim());

        // Envío de correos
        try
        {
            smtpClient.Send(correoParaAdmin);
            smtpClient.Send(correoParaUsuario);

            // Liberar recursos utilizados
            correoParaAdmin.Dispose();
            correoParaUsuario.Dispose();

            lblError.Text = "Registro realizado con exito. Ya puede loguearse.";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = "Error al enviar los correos electrónicos: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblError.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        lblError.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}

Me interesa saber si la demora es producto de mi operación, o si se trata de alguna configuración que deba mejorar en mi hosting. Sinceramente es mi primera Aplicación web que lanzo como freelance y estoy tratando de optimizarla lo más posible,
Muchas Gracias desde ya por su ayuda!

Puedes mostrar el tab de network durante la carga y saber exactamente donde está la demora. Apreta F12, anda a network, activa la grabacion, y dale un CTRL F5 a la página, luego comparte el resultado.

@Excorpion no le va a mostrar nada porque todo pasa en el back...

Apuesto a que los envios de los mails estan tardando mil años.. probaste cuanto tarda sin mandar mails? y si es por ahi, porque haces esas actividades sincronicas en lugar de asincronicas...

El resto, falta codigo para tracear, pero casi 100% seguro que tu problema esta ahi.. en general el envio de mails se encola y se hace por otro lado.. sobre todo porque si esta fallando un servidor de mail (algo re comun), no trabe todo.. simplemente se espera y se envia cuando este disponible...

Probé hacer el envío de mails de forma asincronica, pero igual demora. Voy a probar hacer solo el registro y descartar el envío de mails, al menos ahí ya puedo descartar que sea una cosa o la otra

En efecto, al no enviar los correos, el registro se produce de forma normal, sin demoras.
Entonces... la mejor forma si quiero mandar los correos sería de forma asincronica?
